# How to integrate cakephp in eclipse IDE?

Tags: cakephp

i AM New to cakephp framework.please tell me how to work with the cakephp in eclipse Ide.please give the right instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working in CakePHP you may use Netbeans 7.* or PhpStorm instead of eclipse. Thats IDE support you more than eclipse and have built in CakePHP feature.

If your IDE is not ready for PHP development , then goes through the way :

Open Eclipse and go to Help-> Software Updates-> Find and Install Select "Search for new features to install" and click "Next" Create a New Remote Site with the following details:

Name: PDT

URL: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/release

Check the PDT box and click "Next" to start the installation

Hope it helps

In eclipse you may try with this [CakePHP Plugin For Eclipse](https://github.com/doapp/cakephp-eclipse-plugin)  . I think it will help you.

Comment: I already install the eclipse IDE only for java.now i want eclipse IDE for cakephp also.that my question.please instruct me.

Comment: No.In my local ststem eclipse ide install only for java.

Comment: welcome ,you should follow last line of my answer for your question.